# Font Awesome showing and not showing (concrete5)

Tags: html, font-awesome, concrete5

My website runs on Concrete5.

I wanted to add some more Font Awesome icon to an existing page, but it's not showing. Strange thing is, there already are icons on my webpage and they are showing...

However when I edit the block with the icons in it to check the HTML, there is no HTML/CSS saying the icons should be there!

When I add an icon in the content block in HTML, nothing shows. But when I add an icon with an HTML block it does show.

For instance the tree columns underneath the green picture show three green check boxes.

And this is what the content block says is in the block:

```
<p>Sessie 1</p>
<p>Analyse van je proces van vliegangst en je omslagpunt</p>
<p>Stoppen van de angst, piekeren en vervelende herinneringen</p>
<p>Praktische oefeningen voor thuis</p>
```

[See the website here](http://www.hoffmeistercoaching.nl/vliegangst-overwinnen/cursus-vliegangst-overwinnen/)

As you can see, there is no font-awesome css in there. But icons are showing on the webpage. The css is also showing when you check the html of the page.

Now, if I would put

```
<p> <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> test</p>
```

In the same block (a content block, in the html window). It won't show a camera. It would just show "test".

If I then go back to the content block and see what's in the html, it says

```
<p>test</p>
```

Now if I would put the same line of code in an HTML block, it *does* show the camera icon.

So there are two things happening:

1. Older font-awesome icons are showing on the webpage but not in the content blocks html.
2. New font-awesome icons can't be added through html in content blocks, but can in HTML blocks.

*Edit:* When I use this code:

```
<p class="fa fa-camera-retro"></p>
```

It does show in the content block. But then I can't simply add a symbol with some text, because the font will be from the font-awesome font.

the  `<i>` tag still isn't working.
so

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

Gives nothing.

The icons only appear when there's text between the code:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro">foo</i>
```

However, the editor changes the `<i>` tag then to an `<em>` tag. And 'foo' then has the font-awesome font. Not the font of my website.

****SOLUTION****
If I do it like this:

```
<p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro">&nbsp;</i> some text</p>
```

Everything works as I want.

---

Still, all the older font-awesome css from the website is missing from the content blocks, but it is rendering when I view the website in a browser. If anyone has a suggestion how that can be fixed?

Comment: some code would be helpful. which font awesome icons are you trying to include and where?

Comment: Kind of vague this question. What are you doing? Where do you enter it? I see the thumbs up, i see the check boxes, i see the quotation, and even the checks at your ul class in the text. What should I not see?

Comment: It's my first time on stackoverflow. Sorry I wasn't that clear... I adjusted my question.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on your page:

[image]

It should be **`<p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> some text</p>`**

**Result:**

[image]

---

So basically what you need to so is just change this

```
<p>fa-camera-retro</p>
```

to this

```
<p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> some text</p>
```

Comment: How would I make it so that the 'some text' would be in the same font as all the other text?

Comment: enclose the icon class inside the paragraph tags like this: `<p><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> sometext</p>`

Comment: That doesn't work. It still leaves it out because there's no text within the `<i>` tag.

Comment: those `<i>..</i>` tags aren't really supposed to have any text in between. see these [Font Awesome Examples](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/). Now I am having doubts on what exactly you are trying to do; can you illustrate it using some image?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I think I see your problem. You entered a new HTMLblock, and just pasted in the fa-camera-retro. FontAwesome works as a class and should be entered within a tag.

You can use the `<i>` tag for it, but also the `<p>` tag or whatever you want. It should be then something like

`<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>` (dont forget the extra fa class to make it appear as a font awesome.

Comment: I'm aware of this. This is not the problem. The problem is that content blocks just throw aways the <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"> </i> stuff away. I edited my post to clear it up.

Comment: OK, so when I use the <i> tag, it doesn't work, but when I use the <p> tag it does work...

Comment: What kind of editor is it? It might be that your editor sees <i> blocks as italic blocks and converts it to italic text.

Comment: It's tinyMCE and you're right, it does change it to italics.

Comment: Alright, i suggest you leave the `<i>` tag out for now, since tinymce indeed sees the `<i>, <b> and <u>` tag as markup, which html ignores, except when text is in it. a mark-up editor will spot it, without content, already as markup and will convert that area, despite your class, to italic. Safer to go with a `<p>` tag or maybe even a `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth remembering for the future that when you use the content block, TINYMCE automatically strips out some HTML tags by default, this includes `<i>`'s... To prevent TINYMCE from doing this, go to:

Dashboard > System & Settings > BASICS / Rich Text Editor. Once there, select 'Custom' and add the following line

```
verify_html: false
```

For more information, it's worth keeping this in your bookmarks when using Concret5, especially the content block: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:verify_html

Answer (score 0):

The trick to adding FontAwesome icons in C5 Content blocks is using the em tag along with adding code for non-breaking space between them.

```
<em class="fa fa-camera-retro">&nbsp;</em>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have given your icon any sort of margin, I had the same problem where some icons would make when I checked keenly I noticed I had a CSS rule.

```
p i{
margin-left:10px;
}
```

when I removed that margin all my icons worked.